# FParsec match string which have one of 2 patterns

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm trying to learn FParsec and am trying to match strings which follow on of two patterns.
The string can either be an ordanary string like `"string"` or it can be a string with one dot in it, like `"st.ring"`.

The parser should look like this: `Parser<(string Option * string),unit>`. The first string is optional depending of if the string is splitted by a dot or not. The optional string represent the part of the string which is before the `"."`.

I have tried a few different things but I feel this attempt was the closes:

```
let charstilldot = manyCharsTill anyChar (pstring ".")
let parser = opt(charstilldot) .>>. (many1Chars anyChar)
```

This works with input like this `"st.ring"` but not `"string"` since not dot exists in the latter.

I would verry much appriciate some help, thank you!

**EDIT:**
I have solution which basicly parse the arguments in order and swap the arguments depending of their is a dot or not in the string

```
let colTargetWithoutDot : Parser<string Option,unit> = spaces |>> fun _ -> None
let colTargetWithDot = (pstring "." >>. alphastring) |>> Some
let specificColumn = alphastring .>>. (colTargetWithDot <|> colTargetWithoutDot) |>> (fun (h,t) ->
    match h,t with
    | h,None -> (None,h)
    | h,Some(t) -> (Some(h),t))
```

However this is not pretty so I would still appriciate another solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that `charstilldot` consumes characters even when it fails. In that situation, `many1chars` then fails because the entire input has already been consumed. The easiest way to address this is by using `attempt` to rollback when there is no dot:

```ml
let charstilldot = attempt (manyCharsTill anyChar (pstring "."))
let parser = opt(charstilldot) .>>. (many1Chars anyChar)
```

Result:

- `"str.ing"` -> `(Some "str", "ing")`
- `"string"` -> `(None, "string")`

I think there are other good solutions as well, but I've tried to give you one that requires the least change to your current code.